# How to search by meta and custom taxonomy name - wordpress search?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a ajax search that uses wp_query and I need to be able to filter using custom meta *and* custom taxonomy names. I've gotten the custom meta part working but cannot get it to filter using the taxonomy names. What I've got so far -

```
      $useCustomJoins = false;

       add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $q )
        {
            if( $title = $q->get( '_meta_or_title' ) )
            {
                add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', function( $sql ) use ( $title )
                {
                    global $wpdb;

                    // Only run once:
                    static $nr = 0; 
                    if( 0 != $nr++ ) return $sql;

                    // Modified WHERE
                    $sql['where'] = sprintf(
                        " AND ( %s OR %s ) ",
                        $wpdb->prepare( "{$wpdb->posts}.post_title like '%%%s%%'", $title),
                        mb_substr( $sql['where'], 5, mb_strlen( $sql['where'] ) )
                    );

                    return $sql;
                });
            }
        });

        add_filter('posts_join', array('CrownResources', 'filterPostsJoin'), 10, 2);
        add_filter('posts_where', array('CrownResources', 'filterPostsWhere'), 10, 2);
        add_filter('posts_groupby', array('CrownResources', 'filterPostsGroupby'), 10, 2);

        public static function filterPostsJoin($join, $query) {
            global $wpdb, $useCustomJoins;
            if($useCustomJoins || (is_main_query() && is_search())) {
                $join .= "
                    LEFT JOIN 
                    ( 
                        {$wpdb->term_relationships}
                        INNER JOIN 
                        {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id 
                        INNER JOIN 
                        {$wpdb->terms} ON {$wpdb->terms}.term_id = {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id 
                    ) 
                    ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id ";
            }
            return $join;
        }

        public static function filterPostsWhere($where, $query) {
            global $wpdb, $useCustomJoins;
            if($useCustomJoins || (is_main_query() && is_search())) {
                $userWhere = self::getUserPostsWhere();
                $queryS = !empty(get_query_var('s')) ? get_query_var('s') : get_query_var('_meta_or_title');
                $where .= " OR (
                    {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy IN('resource_pregnancy_taxonomy', 'resource_counseling_taxonomy', 'resource_classes_taxonomy', 'resource_supplies_taxonomy', 'resource_clothing_taxonomy', 'resource_food_taxonomy', 'resource_housing_taxonomy', 'resource_medical_taxonomy', 'resource_substance_taxonomy', 'adoption_taxonomy', 'employment_taxonomy') 
                    AND
                    {$wpdb->terms}.name LIKE '%".esc_sql($queryS)."%'
                    {$userWhere}
                )";
            }
            return $where;
        }

        protected static function getUserPostsWhere() {
            global $wpdb;
            $userId = get_current_user_id();
            $sql = '';
            $status = array("'publish'");
            if(0 !== $userId) {
                $status[] = "'private'";
                $sql .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_author = ".absint($userId);
            }
            $sql .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status IN( ".implode(',', $status)." ) ";
            return $sql;
        }

        public static function filterPostsGroupby($groupby, $query) {
            global $wpdb, $useCustomJoins;
            if($useCustomJoins || (is_main_query() && is_search())) {
                $groupby = "{$wpdb->posts}.ID";
            }
            return $groupby;
        }
```

usage:

```
    global $post, $useCustomJoins;
        $original_post = $post;

        // query for resource
        $queryArgs = array(
            'post_type' => 'resource',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );

        //if taxonomies
        if (!empty($atts['taxonomies'])){
            $queryArgs['tax_query'] = array();

            foreach ($atts['taxonomies'] as $tax){
                $queryArgs['tax_query'][] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => $tax['name'],
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $tax['terms'],
                    'operator' => 'AND',
                );
            }
        }

        // filter by meta as well as title
        $meta_query = array();

        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => 'resource_description',
            'value' => $atts['search'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );

        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => 'resource_address',
            'value' => $atts['search'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );

        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => 'resource_date_time',
            'value' => $atts['search'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );

        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => 'resource_phone',
            'value' => $atts['search'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );

        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => 'resource_email',
            'value' => $atts['search'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );

        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => 'resource_website',
            'value' => $atts['search'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );

        //if there is more than one meta query 'or' then
        if(count($meta_query) > 1) {
            $meta_query['relation'] = 'OR';
        }


        //if there's a search
        if (!empty($atts['search'])){
            // $queryArgs['s'] = $atts['search'];
            $queryArgs['_meta_or_title'] = $atts['search']; //not using 's' anymore
            $queryArgs['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
            $useCustomJoins = true;
        }

        $resourceQuery = new \WP_Query($queryArgs);

        $useCustomJoins = false;
```

Any idea on how to get them working together? I can get the meta filter to search properly but once I add the taxonomy it still filters but not correctly.